# Identify file changes on linux box

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, filesystemwatcher

Is that possible to identify, if a file on a linux box/RDP is modified. I have tried `FileSystemWatcher`, but watching a file on remote server is quite difficult here. Could someone advise me on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can write C, you could give `inotify` a try. It is a kernel feature after 2.6. [Here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478?page=0,1) is a introduce article. And I'm wondering which OS are you using? I thought C# could only used under Windows.